AWS Glue Job with bookmark enabled, Reads same data from S3 CSV file
I have configured a AWS glue job previously
Now I have added option in my CDK to enable/disable/pause bookmark while creating the job using --job-bookmark-option param
I have verified in the AWS console that Job Bookmarking is "Enable" when then above option is set to enable while creating the JOB
Now I am trying to read a CSV file from S3 in the glue job, but even when bookmarking is enabled my glue job reads the whole csv file on every run
Glue Job Code
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

class MyGlueTesJob:
    @classmethod
    def execute(cls, sparkContext: SparkContext, parameters: dict):

        glue_context = GlueContext(sparkContext)

        csvFilePath = parameters.get("csvFilePath")
        jobBookMarkKey = parameters.get("jobBookMarkKey")

        print("S3 Path:", csvFilePath)
        print("Bookmark Key:", jobBookMarkKey)

        if not csvFilePath:
            raise ValueError("S3 path not found in parameters.")

        # Read data from S3 using Glue DynamicFrame
        dynamic_frame = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
            connection_type="s3",
            format="csv",
            connection_options={
                "paths": [csvFilePath],
                "jobBookmarkKeys": [jobBookMarkKey],
                "jobBookmarkKeysSortOrder": "asc"  # Specify the sort order
            },
            transformation_ctx="glueTest"
        )

        dataframe = dynamic_frame.toDF()

        # Print DataFrame content
        print("Content of the DataFrame:")
        dataframe.show()

        print("Parameters:", parameters)

        # Return job result
        return "JobResult"



ETL Script
Class CustomGlueJob
    def main(self):
        args = getResolvedOptions(Sys.argv, [
            self.JOB_NAME, self.JOB_CLASS, self.ARGS,
            self.JOB_ID, self.OPTIONAL_ARGS, self.MODULE
        ])
        print(args)
        glueContext = GlueContext(self.spark_context)
        job = Job(glueContext)
        job.init(args[self.JOB_NAME], args)
        self._jvm.GlueJob.init(self._glue_context, (self._jvm.PythonUtils.toScalaMap(args)))
        result = GlueJob.execute(self.spark_context, args[self.JOB_CLASS], args[self.MODULE_NAME], args[self.JOB_ARGS])
        self._jvm.GlueJob.commit((self._jvm.PythonUtils.toScalaMap(result.toMap())), (self._jvm.PythonUtils.toScalaMap({})))
        job.commit()

glue_job = CustomGlueJob()
glue_job.main()


I have few wrapper classes and I have API to run the job,I may have missed something while editing the code to remove sensitive data in question but everything is working fine and no run time errors, But bookmarking is not working as expected
What I am expecting :

First run : Prints All CSV data
Second run : Should not print anything as no new data is added and bookmarking is enabled
Now add 2 new rows to the CSV file
Third run : Prints only 2 new Rows from CSV as bookmarking is enabled

What I am seeing :

First run : Prints All CSV data
Second run : Prints All CSV data
Now add 2 new rows to the CSV file
Third run : Prints All CSV data


Just to clarify with glue bookmarks and files in s3 it is tracking whether a file has been processed or not, not the actual records within that file.    So you would never have your expected output of the third run only printing the 2 new rows.  It would print all the rows again as modifying the file would cause it to be reprocess, documentation makes note of that https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html

What happens in the second run, it should print empty as I didn't change anything but it is printing all the data again.
And As you mentioned it reprocess the data how can I verify the bookmark functionality in that case, read folder->add new files->read folder again (only new file should be considered) ?

I would have expected with your second run to return nothing and then your third run to return everything again, so to me it appears bookmark isn't working for you.  what is the value for the parameter --job-bookmark-option that you setting? If it is job-bookmark-enable then something in the code isn't right, just not sure what at the moment.

In your CDK code use "--job-bookmark-option": 'job-bookmark-enable'. I think you used 'enable'.

I have verified "--job-bookmark-option": 'job-bookmark-enable' it is setting properly

I had a similar issues and found that, even though you are using job version in the CDK, it keeps recreating the job, thus deleting the job bookmarks.
I tried different ways, but ended up using custom job bookmarks with code as opposed to letting AWS Glue handle it. Each CDK cycle, it will wipe out the job bookmarks - even with job versioning on.
Apparently, it does a silent destroy and then deploy.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
